# Another "and I" vs "and me" question

Tags: pronouns

I see this a lot on Facebook. Two people doing a thing, and the picture captioned with:
"John and I waiting on the bus"
"Mary and I at the Beyonce show"
"Sally and I with our awesome guide Sven"

I think it should be "Joe and me" but I'm not sure why. Is there an implied "this is" at the beginning of each sentence, making Joe and me the object rather than the subject?

Comment: Given that these are just noun phrases, it really could be either. ;) (Joe and I, waiting on the bus, arrived late. A passenger gave a strange orange pill to Joe and me, waiting on the bus.)

Comment: You're correct; the actual rule, as [John McWhorter pointed out in a podcast a couple of years ago](http://podbay.fm/show/500673866/e/1475594208?autostart=1), is that the first person singular pronoun is _me_. The form _I_ only occurs when it is the only pronoun to be the subject of the verb following, and it's normally contracted whenever possible, which is most of the time.

Comment: I couldnt help directing this to: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488446/another-and-i-vs-and-me-question